# Replicating CouchDB data from remote server to local computer

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

I've recently started playing with CouchDB and just into some small issues.

I am trying to replicate data from a aremote server to my remote computer using 
the following command:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"source":"http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5984/testing_replicate","target":"http://localhost:5984:testing_replicate"}' http://localhost:5984/_replicate
```

Somehow there is no response from this command.

Doing `curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/`
and

```
curl -X GET http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5984/
```

returns the expected response : `{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"0.10.0"}`

can anyone enlighten me?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a goof in your target URL.  Change:

```
... "target":"http://localhost:5984:testing_replicate" ...
                                   ^
```

to

```
... "target":"http://localhost:5984/testing_replicate" ...
                                   ^
```

Comment: hi, ok i realized that. Thanks!